# Scrollview auto scroll on Enter key of Soft input keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple layout with nested elements in its xml inside a `ScrollView`, Its basically a form to get user input with multiple `EditText` and Other objects.
One of my `EditText` has attribute

```
android:lines="2"
```

for user address field and it must have 2 lines. So when user make input to the `EditText`, Enter key is shown on the soft input keyboard and on repeated press of this enter key main `Scrollview` auto scrolls to bottom on every click of Enter and EditText loses its focus and layout auto scrolls down to bottom of it. How to stop this from happening.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rel_main_footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/enquiry_header" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_wit_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/wit_head"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#7f0100" />
        <!-- Owner Details -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/li1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_wit_header"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_wit_owner"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/wit_name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_wit_owner"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="@string/hint_set_owner"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#7f0000"
                android:textColorHint="#a65b5a" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/v1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/li1"
            android:background="#A4A4A4" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/li2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/v1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_wit_address"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/ud_address"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_wit_address"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="@string/hint_set_address"
                android:lines="2"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="#7f0000"
                android:textColorHint="#a65b5a" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/v2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/li2"
            android:background="#A4A4A4" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/li3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/v2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_wit_number"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/wit_number"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_wit_number"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="@string/hint_wit_number"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#7f0000"
                android:textColorHint="#a65b5a" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/v3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/li3"
            android:background="#A4A4A4" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/li4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/v3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_wit_notes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/wit_notes"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_wit_notes"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="@string/hint_wit_notes"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="5"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:textColor="#7f0000"
                android:textColorHint="#a65b5a" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try to add this line in your activity declaration on AndroidManifest.xml - android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: No this is not working

Comment: Please replace this properties from Address EditText                           
android:singleLine="true",android:scrollbars="vertical",android:minLines="2" Replace with this android:minLines="2"

Answer (score 1):

**Its not a 100% correct solution for your problem but it may be solve this problem**

```
et_wit_address.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {
            scrollview.scrollTo(0, et_wit_number.getTop());
                        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {
            scrollview.scrollTo(0, et_wit_number.getTop());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            scrollview.scrollTo(0, et_wit_number.getTop());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [android:imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) for handling that extra button on your keyboard.

**ActionNext :**

the action key performs a "next" operation, taking the user to the next field that will accept text.

**ActionDone**

the action key performs a "done" operation, typically meaning there is nothing more to input and the IME will be closed.

Example :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```